# How to import bootstrap-daterangepicker in Angular 4 project?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

I tried following instructions from **[this](https://medium.com/@NetanelBasal/typescript-integrate-jquery-plugin-in-your-project-e28c6887d8dc)** tutorial to integrate bootstrap-daterangepicker in my Angular 4 project but I get the following error and warning.  The error line is: `Uncaught TypeError: __webpack_require__.i(...) is not a function`.  Would anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: I [added a comment to that effect](https://medium.com/@aluanhaddad/is-invalid-semantically-as-ecmascript-which-forbids-calling-module-namespace-objects-35e0fccfc78a) to the article as well.

Comment: Use new datepickers compatible with angular 4 like https://mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/sample/

Comment: @MohammadDayyan that's nice that you made your own datepicker, but this is not an Angular version compatibility problem.

Comment: try `npm update`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the tutorial uses invalid ESM -> CommonJS interop. Use `import $ from jQuery;` instead. Calling a namespace import (`* as`) is invalid in ECMAScript.

**TLDR:** write

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap-daterangepicker';
```

and set `--allowSyntheticDefaultImports` (`"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` in `"compilerOptions"`) so that TypeScript typechecks code using the synthesized default import correctly.

I added [a comment to that effect](https://medium.com/@aluanhaddad/is-invalid-semantically-as-ecmascript-which-forbids-calling-module-namespace-objects-35e0fccfc78a) to the article as well.

**Details:**

Basically, the ECMASCript specification forbids calling [Module Namespace Objects](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-module-namespace-objects) as functions. When you use the syntax

```
import * as imported from 'some-module';
```

A module namespace object named `imported` is created. This objects exposes each export of the specified module for qualified access such as `imported.a` where `a` is exported by `'some-module'`. However, in an AMD or CommonJS module that only exports a single value it is common to export this value *as* the module itself. This is typically written as

```
// AMD
define(function () {
  const $ = {...}; // jquery implementation

  return $;
});
```

Or

```
// CommonJS
const $ = {...}; // jquery implementation

module.exports = $;
```

The value returned by `define` or the value assigned to `module.exports` represent the module itself.

To import such an *export* one would typically write

```
// AMD
define(["jquery"], function ($) {
  $('div').text('set via jQuery');
});
```

Or

```
// CommonJS
const $ = requere("jquery");
$('div').text('set via jQuery');
```

Compare that to a named export typically written as

```
// AMD
define(function () {
  const $ = {...}; // jquery implementation

  return {$};
});
```

Or

```
// CommonJS
const $ = {...}; // jquery implementation

module.exports.$ = $;
```

To import such an *export* one would typically write

```
// AMD
define(["jquery"], function ($) {
  $.$('div').text('set via jQuery');
});
```

Or

```
// CommonJS
const $ = require("jquery");
$.$('div').text('set via jQuery');
```

Now back in the ES Module world, the `* as` syntax aggregates the named exported bindings into an object for dotted (`.`) access.

In sharp contrast to AMD and CommonJS modules, in an ES Module everything exported must exported under a *name*.

However, the utility and simplicity of exporting and importing a single value representing the module itself is still provided for in ES Modules by way of the `default` export/import syntax and semantics. That syntax is

```
// ESM
const something = {...};
export default $;
```

And is typically consumed as

```
// ESM
import $ from 'some-module';
```

This is conceptually similar to assigning to `module.exports` or returning a single value from `define` but in actuality, `default` is not anonymous it is an export *named* `default`.

So the question becomes, when we have an AMD or CommonJS module that exports a value *as* the module itself (usually using one of the patterns described above), how do we import it into an ES Module? `require` is not available to us. We cannot import something without a name. Well interop, while somewhat in flux is to make the value of `module.exports` or that returned by `define` available as the `default` export. This poses a number of problems but it allows us to write

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

This is viable because `default` which is just an export named `default` can be called. A namespace cannot be called.

Unfortunately, due to fluctuations in the ES Module spec, the uncertainty of an interop mechanism every being specified, and for various historical reasons, TypeScript has historically gone a different rout, taking

```
import * as imported from 'some-module';
```

to imply

```
const imported = require('some-module');
```

At the *type* level. Furthermore, it does not *yet* automatically provide values exported as AMD and CommonJS Modules as the `default` which means that the correct syntax can fail at runtime.

However, TypeScript *is* going to address this.

In the meantime, if you use a module interop aware tool such as SystemJS or Webpack 3, you can correctly write

```
import imported from 'some-module';
```

today in TypeScript.
Specify the `--allowSyntheticDefaultImports` compiler option to enable proper typechecking of this syntax against AMD or CommonJS modules.

Comment: Hi @Aluan, thanks for your reply.  I tried your suggestion but now have a different error:  `ERROR in C:/Users/.../app.component.ts (6,8): Module ''jquery'' has no default export`.  Jquery was actually working fine with `import * as $ from 'jquery';`Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I also tried `import daterangepicker from 'bootstrap-daterangepicker';`  instead of  `require('bootstrap-daterangepicker');` as suggested in that tutorial.  And yet again a different error that daterangepicker is not a function:  
`ERROR TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4_jquery__(...).daterangepicker is not a function`

Comment: You are missing `--allowSyntheticDefaultImports` See the last line of my answer. Add that to your `tsconfig`.

Comment: `import daterangepicker from 'bootstrap-daterangepicker';` is not going to work because the datepicker module doesn't export _anything_, it mutates the `'jquery'` module. use `import 'bootstrap-daterangepicker';` as it says in the tutorial.

Comment: @AIuan, thanks for your replies. I tried both changes, jquery works again, but I'm back to the first error mentioned in the screenshot

Comment: @SriramRanganathan that is not very specific. How are you importing `'bootstrap-daterangepicker'`?

Comment: I tried the following:  `import $ from 'jquery';`  and  `import 'bootstrap-daterangepicker';`  also added `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` to tsconfig.json`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156415/discussion-between-aluan-haddad-and-sriram-ranganathan).